# Updating the Height Constraint of a View Inside of a UIStackView

Tags: swift, dynamic, height, constraints, stackview

Currently, I set the height and width constraints of one of my views that I later add to the stack view as follows: (For your information, productsTable is a UITableView.)

```
    productsTable.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(tableHeight).active = true
    productsTable.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(stackWidth).active = true
    stackView.insertArrangedSubview(productsTable, atIndex: productsTableIndex)
```

Later, in ViewWillAppear, I want to change the productsTable height as follows:

```
productsTable.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(newHeight).active = true.
```

Despite this, the table view remains the same size after (changing/updating) the constraint in ViewWillAppear. Is there anything I am doing wrong or can do differently to achieve the desired effect?

Comment: Should you be modifying `productsTable.heightAnchor` instead of `productsTable.widthAnchor`?

Comment: Sorry about that, that was a typo when I wrote the question, but yeah, that doesn't solve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to keep a reference to the height constraint that you create the first time.

```
let heightConstraint = productsTable.heightAnchor.constraintEqualToConstant(tableHeight)
heightConstraint.active = true
```

Later, in viewWillAppear() you'll be able to directly set the constant attribute of this constraint to newHeight.

```
heightConstraint.constant = newHeight
```

Comment: If this solve your problem can you please upvote the answer? Thanks ;)

Comment: Hey Terry, I would but apparently I don't have access to that until I earn a reputation of at least 15